# tiled floor textures

Tags: gazebo-2.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,
I am trying to put some textures on the ground plane of my world file (I need features for the optical flow). I have a picture of the floor of the arena and I would like to use it as a texture. However, the picture itself is much smaller than the arena and setting the  attribute in the sdf file will stretch it, lowering the overall resolution.

What I would like to do is tiling the texture over all the floor. How can I do it?
Here my material script

```
material labrob/cobblestone { 
receive_shadows on  
technique   {
       pass 
       {    
        ambient 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000         
            emissive 0.000000 0.0000000 0.000000 1.000000
            lighting on         
            texture_unit        {       
          texture cobblestone.jpg       
           }    
       }    
   } 
}
```

Thank you very much

Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7393/tiled-floor-textures/) by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could use `scale` inside your `texture_unit` to repeat the texture several times in the same area. The [asphalt_plane](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/74a580447dd670bc78f9f9e476a6d5d3ffd69563/asphalt_plane/materials/scripts/asphalt.material?at=default) is a good example, there the texture is repeated 10 times in each direction.

The [scale](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_17.html#scale) should be [1 1] by default, a scale of [0.5 0.5] would repeat the texture twice in each direction and so on.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on 2015-06-23**:
That solved my problem. Thank you very much!